# Prove that $\sum_{\substack{0<k<3^n\\3\nmid k}}\sigma{(3^n-k)}\sigma{(k)}=6\cdot27^{n-1}$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

A similar problem to [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445680/how-prove-this-sum-k-12n-1-sigma2n-2k1-sigma2k-1-8n-1) (ccorn has given a nice answer to it). Prove that
$$\sum_{\substack{0<k<3^n\\3\nmid k}}\sigma{(3^n-k)}\sigma{(k)}=6\cdot27^{n-1},$$ 
where $\sigma(N)$ is defined as $$\sigma{(N)}=\sum_{d\mid N}d.$$

I find this:(From *Elementary Evaluation of Certain Convolution Sums Involving Divisor Functions* by Huard et al. On page 20)

[image]

so we are done.

Comment: Note that, $$\sum_{0<k<n}\sigma(n-k)\sigma(k)-\sum_{0<k<\frac{n}{3}}\sigma(n-3k)\sigma(3k)=\sum_{0<k<3^n}_{3\nmid k}\sigma(n-k)\sigma(k)$$

Comment: @EthanNotify Are there formulas for the sums on the left hand ?(I think not, otherwise ccorn will not write a long proof for that problem.)

Comment: The first sum on the lhs, $$\sum_{0<k<n}\sigma(n-k)\sigma(k)=\frac{5\sigma_3(n)-(6n-1)\sigma(n)}{12}$$

Comment: @Ethan That's interesting, thank you.

Comment: http://paramanands.blogspot.com/search?q=lambert+series describes some elementary techniques for deriving similar identities.

Comment: @Ethan Thank you. I can not open this link, but i have got the answer.

Comment: @Angela Richardson It's not true, in fact, for $p>3$ I can not find a similar formula.

Comment: @ccorn Why did you delete your answer? I'm going to read it again but it's gone..

Comment: @Hecke: It was correct, but it was not elegant enough to be easily verifiable, and the generalized result is not particularly pretty. The basic idea is simple (use generating functions); but the details turn out to be calculations for which you will need pencil and paper and quite a bit of patience. I figured that that was not the type of answer that MSE is meant to handle, and since there was no feedback at all, I took the freedom to delete it. Oh well. Here is it again, undeleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $p$ prime and $n$ a nonnegative integer, define

$$f_p(n) = \sum_{\substack{k=1,\ldots,p^n-1\\p\not\mid k}}
\sigma(k)\,\sigma(p^n - k)$$

Proposition:

$$f_p(n)=\begin{cases}
 0 & \text{for }n=0
\\[1ex] \frac{1}{12}\,\frac{p^2 - 1}{p^2 + 1}
 \left(5 (p - 1)\,p^{3n-1} - (p - 2)(p - 3)(-p)^{n-1}\right)
 & \text{for }n \geq 1
\end{cases}$$
This confirms the previous result for $p=2$ and the claim for $p=3$
and generalizes the formula to arbitrary primes $p$.
I actually had hoped for a formula that is as simple for $p>3$ as it is
for $p=2$ and $p=3$, but as you can see, this is not the case.

To establish that result, I will use generating functions,
along with a formula supplied by Ethan, which I will prove first.

As
[before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445680/how-prove-this-sum-k-12n-1-sigma2n-2k1-sigma2k-1-8n-1),
we will use the Ramanujan functions $P(q)$ and $Q(q)$
and the corresponding normalized Eisenstein series $\mathrm{E}_2(\tau)$
and $\mathrm{E}_4(\tau)$ via $q = \mathrm{e}^{2\pi\mathrm{i}\tau}$
where $\tau$ ranges over the complex upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$:

$$\begin{aligned}
 \mathrm{E}_2(\tau) &= P(q) =
 1 - 24\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sigma(n)\,q^n
\\ \mathrm{E}_4(\tau) &= Q(q) =
 1 + 240\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sigma_3(n)\,q^n
\end{aligned}$$

When looking at the formula supplied by Ethan,

$$\sum_{k=1,\ldots,n-1} \sigma(k)\,\sigma(n - k) =
\frac{1}{12}\left(5\sigma_3(n) - (6n - 1)\,\sigma(n)\right)$$
it is helpful to think about generating functions.
You will recognize the $\sigma_3$ as coming from $Q$
and the $\sigma$ as coming from $P$.
Finally, the $n$ in the factor $(6n-1)$ comes from... differentiation. Yes.

In terms of generating functions, the formula is actually quite famous:

$$P^2 = Q + 12q\frac{\mathrm{d}P}{\mathrm{d}q}$$
It is part of a triplet of equations that relate Ramanujan's functions
$P$, $Q$, $R$ with their derivatives. But how can we prove it, elegantly?

Key facts are again the modular symmetries of the Eisenstein series.
Let $\tau' = \frac{-1}{\tau}$, then

$$\begin{aligned}
 \mathrm{E}_2(\tau+1) &= \mathrm{E}_2(\tau)
& \mathrm{E}_2(\tau') &=
 \frac{6\tau}{\pi\,\mathrm{i}} + \tau^2\,\mathrm{E}_2(\tau)
\\ \mathrm{E}_4(\tau+1) &= \mathrm{E}_4(\tau)
& \mathrm{E}_4(\tau') &= \tau^4\,\mathrm{E}_4(\tau)
\end{aligned}$$
These symmetries are demonstrated in introductory textbooks such as

1. Tom M. Apostol,
   Modular Functions and Dirichlet Series in Number Theory;
   2nd edition 1990; Springer, ISBN 0-387-97127-0; 1st edition 1976.

Differentiating the formula for $\mathrm{E}_2(\tau')$ with respect to $\tau$,
you will find

$$\mathrm{E}_2'(\tau') =
\frac{6\tau^2}{\pi\,\mathrm{i}} + 2\tau^3\,\mathrm{E}_2(\tau)
+ \tau^4\,\mathrm{E}_2'(\tau)$$
Now let

$$L = \mathrm{E}_2^2 - \frac{6}{\pi\mathrm{i}}\,\mathrm{E}_2'$$
and examine what happens to $L$ under the transformations
$\tau\to\tau+1$ and $\tau\to\tau'$. You will find:

$$\begin{aligned}
 L(\tau+1) &= L(\tau)
\\ L(\tau') &= \left(\frac{6\tau}{\pi\mathrm{i}} +
 \tau^2\mathrm{E}_2(\tau)\right)^2 - \frac{6}{\pi\mathrm{i}}
 \left(\frac{6\tau^2}{\pi\,\mathrm{i}} + 2\tau^3\,\mathrm{E}_2(\tau)
 + \tau^4\,\mathrm{E}_2'(\tau)\right)
\\ &= \tau^4\left(\mathrm{E}_2^2(\tau) -
 \frac{6}{\pi\mathrm{i}}\,\mathrm{E}_2'(\tau)\right)
\\ &= \tau^4\,L(\tau)
\end{aligned}$$
That is, $L$ has the same modular symmetries as $\mathrm{E}_4$.
Furthermore, from its definition in terms of $\mathrm{E}_2$, we see that
$L$ is holomorphic over $\mathbb{H}$ and has a Maclaurin series in $q$.
Thus, $L$ is an entire modular form of weight $4$.

As Apostol shows in his modular functions text (chapter 6, section 5),
there exists, up to a constant factor, just one entire modular form
of weight $4$, and that is $\mathrm{E}_4$.
In fact, by comparing limits for $\Im\tau\to\infty$ (thus forcing $q\to0$),
we find that the factor is $1$, so $L = \mathrm{E}_4$.

There it is again: Finding modular symmetries with low weights
can suffice to identify functions.
You must make sure however that the function you examine has no poles,
not even for $\Im\tau\to\infty$ where $q\to0$.
This necessitates the above checks about being holomorphic and
having a Maclaurin series. However, all this turns out to be amazingly easy.

Knowing that $L=\mathrm{E}_4$, we can now express the derivative of
$\mathrm{E}_2$ in terms of $\mathrm{E}_2$ and $\mathrm{E}_4$. Thus we find

$$\mathrm{E}_2^2 = \mathrm{E}_4 +
\frac{6}{\pi\mathrm{i}}\,\mathrm{E}_2'$$
Note that $q\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}q} =
\frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\tau}$.
This allows us to translate $\frac{6}{\pi\mathrm{i}}\mathrm{E}_2'$ to
$12q\frac{\mathrm{d}P}{\mathrm{d}q}$. Altogether,

$$P^2 = Q + 12q\frac{\mathrm{d}P}{\mathrm{d}q}$$
which is what I wanted to prove.

We will now express the above result using $q$-series.
For positive integer $m$, define

$$s(m) = \sum_{k=1,\ldots,m-1} \sigma(k)\,\sigma(m - k)$$
Its generating $q$-series is

$$\begin{aligned}
 \sum_{m=1}^\infty s(m)\,q^m &= \left(\frac{1-P(q)}{24}\right)^2
\\ &= \frac{1 - 2P(q) + P^2(q)}{24^2} =
 \frac{1 - 2P(q) + Q(q) + 12q\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}q}P(q)}{24^2}
\\ &= \frac{1}{12} \sum_{m=1}^\infty
 \left((1 - 6m)\,\sigma(m) + 5\sigma_3(m)\right) q^m
\end{aligned}$$
Comparing coefficients yields the formula supplied by Ethan.

The modular stuff ends here. Below, I will merely use generating functions
such as $\frac{1}{1-X} = 1 + X + X^2 + \cdots$ which should be familiar.

Now we focus on those $m$ that we are interested in.
For prime $p$ and nonnegative integer $n$, let

$$\begin{aligned}
 h_p(n) = s(p^n) &= \frac
 {5 (p^{3(n+1)} - 1) - (p^2+p+1)(6 p^n - 1)(p^{n+1} - 1)}
 {12 (p^3 - 1)}
\\ &= \frac
 {(5p^3)\,p^{3n} - \left(6 p\,(p^2+p+1)\right) p^{2n}
 + \left((p+6)(p^2+p+1)\right) p^n - (p^2+p+6)}
 {12 (p^3 - 1)}
\end{aligned}$$
(To ease things, separate factors $p^{3n}, p^{2n}, p^n$ from factors
with constant exponents.)

It is time to note a relationship of $h_p$ with the $f_p$ we are looking for:

$$\begin{aligned}
 h_p(n) = s(p^n) &=
 \sum_{k=1,\ldots,p^n-1} \sigma(k)\,\sigma(p^n - k)
\\ &= \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}
 \sum_{\substack{
 k=1,\ldots,p^{n-j}-1\\p\not\mid k}}
 \sigma(k\,p^j)\,\sigma(p^n - k\,p^j)
\\ &= \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \sigma(p^j)^2
 \sum_{\substack{
 k=1,\ldots,p^{n-j}-1\\p\not\mid k}}
 \sigma(k)\,\sigma(p^{n-j} - k)
\\ &= \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \sigma(p^j)^2\,f_p(n-j)
 = \sum_{j=0}^{n} \sigma(p^j)^2\,
 \underbrace{f_p(n-j)}_{0\text{ for }j=n}
\end{aligned}$$
In pulling out $\sigma(p^j)^2$, we use the fact that $\sigma$
is multiplicative for coprime factors of its arguments.

Consequently, when using generating functions

$$\begin{aligned}
 F_p(X) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_p(n)\,X^n
\\ G_p(X) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sigma(p^n)^2\,X^n
\\ H_p(X) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty h_p(n)\,X^n
\end{aligned}$$
we find

$$\begin{aligned}
 H_p(X) &= G_p(X)\,F_p(X)
\end{aligned}$$
Henceforth, expressions with $X$ shall implicitly be understood as the
corresponding formal power series. We will not evaluate the series at any
particular $X$, so we do not need to address issues of domain and convergence.

The generating function $H_p(X)$ is

$$\begin{aligned}
 H_p(X) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty h_p(n)\,X^n
\\ &= \frac{1}{12 (p^3 - 1)}\left(
 \frac{5p^3}{1 - p^3 X} - \frac{6\,p(p^2+p+1)}{1 - p^2 X}
 + \frac{(p+6)(p^2+p+1)}{1 - p X} - \frac{(p^2+p+6)}{1 - X}\right)
\\ &= \frac{(p^2 - 1)}{12}\,\frac{(5 p - 6) X + p^3 X^2}
 {(1 - p^3 X)(1 - p^2 X)(1 - p X)(1 - X)}
\end{aligned}$$

The generating function $G_p(X)$ is

$$\begin{aligned}
 G_p(X) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sigma(p^n)^2\,X^n
\\ &= \frac{1}{(p - 1)^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty
 \left(p^{n+1} - 1\right)^2\,X^n
\\ &= \frac{1}{(p - 1)^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty
 \left(p^2\,p^{2n} -2p\,p^n + 1\right)\,X^n
\\ &= \frac{1}{(p - 1)^2} \left(\frac{p^2}{1 - p^2 X}
 - \frac{2p}{1 - p X} + \frac{1}{1 - X}\right)
\\ &= \frac{1 + p X}{(1 - p^2 X)(1 - p X)(1 - X)}
\end{aligned}$$

Therefore

$$\begin{aligned}
 F_p(X) &= \frac{H_p(X)}{G_p(X)} = \frac{p^2 - 1}{12}
 \,\frac{(5 p - 6) X + p^3 X^2}{(1 - p^3 X)(1 + p X)}
\\ &= \frac{1}{12}\,\frac{p^2 - 1}{p^2 + 1}
 \left(\frac{p^2}{1 - p^3 X} + \frac{1}{1 + p X}\right)
 \left((5 p - 6) X + p^3 X^2\right)
\\ &= \frac{1}{12}\,\frac{p^2 - 1}{p^2 + 1}
 \Biggl((p^2 + 1)(5 p - 6) X +
\\ &\qquad\qquad\qquad \sum_{n=2}^\infty
 \left((5 p - 6) \left(p^{3(n-1)+2} + (-p)^{n-1}\right)
 + p^3 \left(p^{3(n-2)+2} + (-p)^{n-2}\right)\right) X^n\Biggr)
\\ &= \frac{1}{12}\,\frac{p^2 - 1}{p^2 + 1}
 \left((p^2 + 1)(5 p - 6) X + \sum_{n=2}^\infty
 \underbrace{\left(5 (p - 1)\,p^{3n-1}
 - (p - 2)(p - 3)(-p)^{n-1}\right)}_{=(p^2+1)(5p-6)\text{ for }n=1}
 X^n\right)
\\ &= \frac{1}{12}\,\frac{p^2 - 1}{p^2 + 1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty
 \left(5 (p - 1)\,p^{3n-1} - (p - 2)(p - 3) (-p)^{n-1}\right) X^n
\end{aligned}$$
This proves the proposition.
Let me point out that the modular part was almost effortless in comparison.

Comment: +1 for this really well written answer with all the details included.